# Añadir un campo generado manualmente a unos array generados de una base de datos

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Estoy intentando comprender algo en programación php.
Tengo un array principal, que contiene otros arrays
adjunto fotografía para mejor compresión.

[image: Resultado Inicial]

Todos los datos son generados de la base de datos y quiero hacer una prueba y añadir un campo generado manualmente a cada uno de los arrays.

El campo será la union del campo nombre con el campo apellido,
algo así

Resultado es el array que almacena todos los campos de la base de datos

```
foreach ($resultado as $resultados)
     {     
            $resultad[] = $resultados["nombre"].' '.$resultados["apellido"];
   $resultado = array_add($resultado,'nombre_completorrrr',$resultad);
         }
```

El problema es que ese campo me lo añade pero fuera de todos los arrays, me crea un array al final y me lo añade allí, lo que quiero es que lo genere como un elemento de cada uno de los arrays.

Estoy usando laravel, y tengo activada la opción de usar arrays en config/database,

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,

Anteriormente usando objetos lo consigo pero si lo intento con arrays solo me lo genera al final y no como un elemento más.
La idea seria que aparezca así

```
    Array(
    array('nombre =>ramon',
        'apellido => perez',
        ...
        ...
        nombre_completo => 'ramon perez',
        ),
    array('nombre' =>'ramon',
        'apellido' => 'garcia',
        ...
        ...
        nombre_completo => 'ramon garcia',
        ),
 etc
        Etc
)
)
```

y no asi

```
  array(
    array('nombre =>ramon',
        'apellido => perez',
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ),
    array('nombre' =>'ramon',
        'apellido' => 'garcia',
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ),
 array(
        nombre_completo => 'ramon perez',
        nombre_completo => 'ramon garcia',    
            )
)
)
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago así, en laravel5 para respuestas json:

```
foreach ($resultado as $resultados)
{     
    $resultados['nombre_completorrrr'] = $resultados["nombre"].' '.$resultados["apellido"];
}
```

no se si te servirá, saludos

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   $nombre = $value['nombre'] . ' ' .$value['apellido'];
   $array[$key] = array_add($value, 'nombre_completo', $nombre);
}
dd($array);
/* esta es la solución
 * de igual manera si estas utilizando un modelo puedes utilizar un Accesor
 * en el modelo con una funcion de getter
*/
protected $appends = [ 'nombre_completo' ];
public function getNombreCompletoAttribute(){
    return $this->nombre. ' ' . $this->apellido;
}
```

Comment: Por favor **[edit] tu respuesta** agregando mas información. Lee **[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Saludos.

Comment: Agrega una explicación aunque sea breve, no solo código.

Answer (score 0):

Según el código de laravel y lo que quieres, creo que debería ser así:

```
foreach ($resultado as $resultados)
{     
    $resultad = $resultados["nombre"].' '.$resultados["apellido"];
    $resultados = array_add($resultados,'nombre_completorrrr',$resultad);
}
```

Referencia de array_add() :

```
/**
 * Add an element to an array using "dot" notation if it doesn't exist.
 *
 * @param  array   $array
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return array
 */
public static function add($array, $key, $value)
{
    if (is_null(static::get($array, $key))) {
        static::set($array, $key, $value);
    }

    return $array;
}
```